# Combo box style not showing selected item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have been given a WPF application despite not knowing much about WPF.
I have a style for a combo box that looks really good but the items appear in the drop down list but the selected item is not appearing in the main text box that is shown when the drop down list is not shown. This simply remains empty.

I am pretty sure I nee to put a content presenter somewhere but the question is where?

I believe this is all of the code relating to this style.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="SearchActionComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="Border"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Background="Green"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="2"
                CornerRadius="3" />
        <Border Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="1"
                Background="White"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1"
                CornerRadius="0" />
        <Path x:Name="Arrow"
              Grid.Column="1"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Data="M0,0 L0,2 L4,6 L8,2 L8,0 L4,4 z"
              Fill="White" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

 <Style x:Key="SearchActionComboBoxMenu" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton"
                                  Grid.Column="2"
                                  ClickMode="Press"
                                  Cursor="Hand"

                                  Focusable="false"
                                  Foreground="Black"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen,
                                                      Mode=TwoWay,
                                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  Template="{StaticResource SearchActionComboBoxToggleButton}" />



                    <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                             Margin="3,3,23,3"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"
                             Background="White"
                             Focusable="True"
                             Foreground="Black"
                             IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
                             Style="{x:Null}"
                             Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                             Visibility="Hidden" />
                    <Popup Name="Popup"
                           Width="200"
                           AllowsTransparency="True"
                           Focusable="False"
                           IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                           Placement="Bottom"
                           PopupAnimation="Slide">

                        <Grid Name="DropDown"
                              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                    Background="White"
                                    BorderBrush="Black"
                                    BorderThickness="1" />
                            <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#888888" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0" />
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false" />
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />

                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers />
</Style>
```

Please let me know if you need any of the other code that may be called that I havent supplied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You havent set contentpresenter in style

```
 <Style x:Key="SearchActionComboBoxMenu" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Grid.Column="2" ClickMode="Press" Cursor="Hand" Focusable="false" Foreground="Black" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Template="{StaticResource SearchActionComboBoxToggleButton}" />

                        //added contentpresenter here

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Margin="3,3,23,3" TextElement.Foreground="Red" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox" Margin="3,3,23,3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="White" Focusable="True" Foreground="Black" IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" Style="{x:Null}" Visibility="Hidden" />
                        <Popup Name="Popup" Width="200" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" Placement="Bottom" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Grid Name="DropDown" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" />
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>

                    ........................

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers />
    </Style>
```

Comment: Awesome dude thanks this works now, Ill accept your anser as soon as I can.